# Can not fetch an image from mnist tfrecord using tf-slim framework

Tags: tensorflow

I used DatasetDataProvider to get an image from tfrecord. I can 'print(image)', but when using 'sess.run(image)' to fetch it, the program seem to fall into a infinite loop. I have no knowledge of whether I have make a mistake.

print(image) get

```
  Tensor("Reshape_3:0", shape=(28, 28, 1), dtype=uint8, device=/device:CPU:0)
```

Full code as below:

```
    from __future__ import absolute_import
    from __future__ import division
    from __future__ import print_function

    import tensorflow as tf

    from datasets import dataset_factory
    from tensorflow.contrib import slim

    dataset = dataset_factory.get_dataset(
        'mnist', 'train', '/home/zehao/Dataset/mnist')

    with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
        provider = slim.dataset_data_provider.DatasetDataProvider(
            dataset,
            num_readers=1,
            common_queue_capacity=20 * 1,
            common_queue_min=10 * 1)
        [image, label] = provider.get(['image', 'label'])

    print(image)

    sess = tf.Session()
    sess.run(image)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `slim.dataset_data_provider` uses TensorFlow [input queues](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/threading_and_queues) under the hood. Therefore, it's important to (after creating your session) add the following 2 lines to kick off the queue runners:

```
coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)
```

For a full example, see: https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/reading_data